# CSS replace <span> text by image inside tag <a href>

Tags: html, css

Is there any way how to hide `span` text inside `a href` tag and replace it with image?

This is my HTML code that I don't want to modify:

```
<div id="social" class="icons">
        <a href="http://twitter.com/" class="twitter"><span>Twitter</span></a>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" class="fb"><span>Facebook</span></a>
        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/" class="linkedin"><span>Linked In</span></a>
</div>
```

In CSS file I'm trying to hide `<span>Twitter</span>` and replace it by image like that:

```
.icons .twitter span {
    display: none;
}
.icons .twitter a {
    text-decoration:none;
    background:url('images/i_twitter.png') no-repeat;
}
```

My issue [code](https://jsfiddle.net/bimbochobot/gmu4m6yy/).

Comment: What action causes the `<span>` to be replaced by a `background-image`?

Comment: Make the `a` tag a block element and give it some dimensions https://jsfiddle.net/gmu4m6yy/4/

Comment: Why not have an `<img>` tag with the desired image instead of the span? No css at all... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not appearing because when setting `display:none` to the span, your anchor has no size. A possible solution is to set the image as a pseudo element, like `:before`

```css
.icons .twitter span {
  display: none;
}
.icons .twitter:before {
  text-decoration:none;
  content: url('http://ecowoodsvillage.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/twitter-icon-small.png');
}
```

```html
<div id="social" class="icons">
  <a href="http://twitter.com/" class="twitter"><span>Twitter</span></a>
  <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" class="fb"><span>Facebook</span></a>
  <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/" class="linkedin"><span>Linked In</span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change display of link and add width and height:

```
.icons .twitter span {
    display: none;
}
.icons > a {  
    display: inline-block;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.icons .twitter {
    background:url('http://ecowoodsvillage.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/twitter-icon-small.png') no-repeat;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/03wg6vzw/

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.

What's happening is by setting `display: none;` on your `span`, you're effectively causing your `a` to have no dimensions (anchors have an `auto` width and height, and there is nothing to "prop" it open so you can see your background image).

You'll need to specify explicit widths and heights for your links, as well as change their `display` from their default (`inline`) to something that allows width and height to be set, like `inline-block`.

```
.icons a{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 64px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -9999px;   /* Hide text in spans this way so it's accessible */
    width: 64px;
}

.icons .twitter span {
    visibility: hidden; /* let's not hide that text for accessibility purposes */
}
.icons .twitter a {
    text-decoration:none;
    background:url('images/i_twitter.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the display to inline-block and setting a width and height for the element should work.

```
.icons span {
    display: none;
}

.icons .twitter, .icons .fb, .icons .linkedin {
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background:url('http://ecowoodsvillage.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/twitter-icon-small.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `a` from class declaration, and add next styles:

```
.icons .twitter {
    text-decoration:none;
    background:url('images/i_twitter.png') no-repeat;
    width: 100px; /* width of the image */
    height: 20px; /* height of the image  */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to span tag. That can be removed. You can do it like this for each class.

```
a.twitter {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: url('images/i_twitter.png') no-repeat;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the span to `color:transparent`.

```
.icons a span {
    color: transparent;
}
.icons .twitter {
    text-decoration:none;
    background:url('http://ecowoodsvillage.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/twitter-icon-small.png') no-repeat;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gmu4m6yy/6/